# WordPress Genesis not excluding category from blog

Tags: categories, blog, genesis-theme-framework

I am trying to exclude a category from my blog. I login to WP and go to Genesis and Theme Settings and add the category IDs to the Blog Page Template area and hit save. Nothing happens.

I have also tried adding the following to my `functions.php` file:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'be_exclude_category_from_blog' );
function be_exclude_category_from_blog( $query ) {

    if( $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_home() ) {
        $query->set( 'cat', '-156' );
    }
}
```

but again nothing happens.

Can anyone point me into the right direction?

Comment: Where did u get the code? Are you referring to your blog page or your home page?

Comment: @BradDalton http://www.wpstuffs.com/exclude-posts-category-front-page-genesis/

Comment: Well its actually Bill Ericksons but been republished so many times. Why don't you ask the site you got the code from, wpstuffs?

Comment: Unfortunately Genesis code isn't publicly available and as such is [not in scope](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here. The filter part looks like it should work though, where/how are you including that code?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you have to set your Blog page to the Blog Page Template for the Genesis Settings Exclude Category to work. So, go to your blog page in WP Admin and select 'Blog' from the Page Template drop down menu.

Comment: Yes, your home page, blob page and front page can all be different depending on reading settings and the blog page template, home.php and front-page.php files used in Genesis